# Remove/Bypass startup script

Tags: scripts, ssh, startup, embedded-system

I am in trouble. I have a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) based embedded device (PLC). I wrote a startup script in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` and created its symlink in Run Level `rc.d` directory. The script is a C program that never terminates. Now, I cannot access my device because every time it starts it gets stuck in that startup script.

Can I somehow ask Ubuntu to ignore the startup script? Although I can ping my device by its IP address, ssh/telnet login fails (Saying `connection refused`) so I cannot login to my device and remove that script manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your post and tell us what device you are talking about? Doing so would help us help you! Thank you.

Comment: On top of the above, what flavour/version are you running?

Comment: It is a PLC. I have edited my post